# Formatear número a dos decimales en javascript sin redondear

Tags: php, javascript

Esta es la solución del método `bdvi(3123.768,1,2)` utilizado en php para formatear el texto a dos decimales sin redondear.

Me pregunté si existe algún método en javascript similar al de `bdiv()` de php que este me ayuda a formatear el texto a solo dos decimales pero la respuesta era el `.tofixed(2)` pero no este método si redondea el número. y yo solo quería dejarlo a dos decimales sin redondear. así que mejor desarrolle el código aquí lo dejo por si a alguien le sirve.

Forma de usar

```
bcdiv(123123.476);
```

Método

```
function bcdiv(num){
    letras = [];
    num = new String(num);
    for(var i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
        letras.push(num.substring(i,i +1));
    }

    cadena = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < letras.length; i++){
        if(num[i] == '.'){
            cadena = cadena + num[i] + num[i +1] + num[i+2];
            break;
        }else{

            cadena = cadena + num[i];
        }
    }
    return parseFloat(cadena);
}
```

Comment: mayúsculas == gritar. Edita tu pregunta por favor. Gracias, por cierto, bienvenido/a a SOes. Detalle importante: lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Hola. Escribí mal la sugerencia: debí escribir `$y = ( (int) (100 * $x) ) / 100;` te arroja lo que necesitas directamente. Eliminé mi comentario anterior porque invitaba al error.

Answer (score 1):

Propongo una implementación del método que acepta por parámetro el número de decimales a mostrar, rellena con ceros por la derecha hasta completar el tamaño indicado:

```
function bcdiv(num, decimales) {
    let num_str = new String(num);
    let pad_ceros = new Array(decimales).fill("0").join('');
    let dot = num_str.indexOf('.');
    if (dot === -1) {
        return num_str + '.' + pad_ceros;
    }
    return num_str.substring(0, dot) + num_str.substr(dot, decimales+1) + pad_ceros.substring(num_str.length - dot - 1);
}
```

Por ejemplo:

```
> bcdiv(12.1, 4)
'12.1000'
> bcdiv(121.319911, 2)
'121.31'
```